# How to paste large code text using %cpaste in ipython?

Tags: python, ipython

I'm trying to paste code into ipython using %cpaste, but whenever the pasted code is too large (almost 100-150 lines of code), it stops actually reading the input buffer and therefore gives me an error similar to:

```
  File "<ipython-input-2-f23a5343110f>", line 133
    return(
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

If it matters, I'm using a `bash` inside an emacs and running `ipython3 -i` from there.

**EDIT:** interestingly if I paste half of the code, hit enter, paste the second half, press enter, then `--`, then enter, it processes it properly.

Comment: are you missing a `)`

Comment: No I'm not, that the problem. It arbitrary stops reading the input buffer, the buffer goes on but is not read by %cpaste.

Comment: @adrin What version of ipython do you use?

Comment: @oren python 3.3.5, ipython 1.2.1, why?

Comment: @adrin I switched to ipython 1.2.1 from ipython 1 and managed to paste some more lines. But there was not big improvement

Comment: @adrin Maybe you can add an example?

Comment: @Oren, it doesn't really matter what code you paste. Just paste a big chunk of code and you get the error. But if you need an example, I just tried copy/pasting [this](https://github.com/adrinjalali/Network-Classifier/blob/master/rat.py) file and got the same error.

Comment: fwiw i see the same limitation when using ipython in the console with tmux and sending code over from vim-slime. it seems that there is a limitation of ~1024 chars after which the input starts to get garbled

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of having this question answered:

As mentioned in the comments, there is a limitation for the size of the pasted code. The limit is increased in recent releases of `ipython`.

So either upgrade you `ipython` (in my setting version 2.3.1 doesn't have that problem, or at least the limit is much larger), or do it as I mentioned in the question:

> paste half of the code, hit enter, paste the second half, press enter,
>   then --, then enter, it processes it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to solve it.
It is not ipython problem it is the terminal console that we use..
I was using `Xfce 0.4.7` and had the problem that you had. When I switch to `Konsole 2.3.3` the problem was solved and I can paste big chunks of text.

It is also possible to do `%paste`, this also solves the problem.